# is c_str() allocate memory in heap?

Tags: c++

Recently i have the problem with c_str().below is the sample code snippet

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;
class har{

    public:
    string h;
    har(string str){
        h=str;
    }
};

int main(){


har *hg=new har("harish");
const char *ptr=hg->h.c_str();
delete hg;
cout<<ptr<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output as "harish"....I have destroyed the object but still i am getting the output..is c_str() again allocating memory in heap.

Comment: Accessing deleted objects is undefined behaviour. And no, `c_str()` simply returns a pointer to the string.

Comment: Also, see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/580083)

Comment: Not related to your question, but the dual combo of [`bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is a bad idea.

Comment: calling delete is meant to tell the os that the specific memory area is free for reuse, not that the whole of it is completely zero'ed out right after that. you'll see this clearer and more often in programs run with repeated uses of dynamic alloc and dealloc functions. 
So only after main or when the objects in use become out of scope, will you be able to enjoy the non-allocated assets.

Comment: If you compile this with MSVC in DEBUG mode then your program will print garbage as MSVC is kind enough to fill deallocated memory with garbage when it frees it: http://rextester.com/HJYZ85336

Answer (score 7):

`c_str()` gives you a pointer to the data buffer in `std::string` (with a `NUL` terminator guaranteed to be added at the end of the string), that's all. Note that the pointer is *invalidated* if the `std::string` goes out of scope, is destroyed, or is changed.

In your case the behaviour of `cout << ptr << endl`; is *undefined*. This is because `ptr` was set to the return value of `c_str()` on a string that no longer exists, and `cout` for `const char*` has a special overload that attempts to read the character buffer from that pointer up to the first NUL character encountered.  The result you observe is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

Note that, `cout << (void*)ptr << endl;` is also undefined, as once you no longer own memory at an address, the pointer is essentially in an uninitialised state.

Comment: Moreover, one should not even attempt to modify the returned string.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yup, the original draft had completely the wrong flavour to it. I've amended.

Comment: we are deleting the object means we are destroying its memory in heap right...why still i am getting the output..can you guys please explain me in little detail as i am new to c++.

Comment: @harishDubakula: The result you observe is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is using the value of `ptr` itself really ok? Isn't the pointer invalid after being freed due to destruction of the owning `std::string`?

Comment: @Deduplicator; I'm checking, frantically. This is a tricky corner of the standard.

Comment: @Deduplicator: You're correct, same as an uninitialised pointer read.

Comment: @harishDubakula `std::string` buffer can live both on the heap and the stack (for small lengths, see SSO). This is irrelevant to your problem as explained by @Bathsheba.

Comment: will that memory of c_str() allocated in heap?

Comment: @Bathsheba `ptr` is a copy of the result of `c_str()`. It's definitely invalidated, but it shouldn't be modified by the destruction of the string. However, I'm also not 100% sure you are allowed to take address value of a pointer to a deleted object in general. For example, you can't read the address from a pointer you `delete` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43508771/7359094)). This doesn't necessarily mean that this example applies to copies of such pointers, but I seem to remember taking the address from a pointer to a deleted object is just UB in general.

Comment: @harishDubakula: It is free, but why would the C++ runtime clean up the memory? That would be a bit like cleaning the holiday cottage yourself before you left.

Comment: @Bathsheba afaik you can cast it to `uintptr_t` and print that without any UB. No one forbids taking integer values of pointers, even if they don't point anywhere useful.

Comment: @DanM.: Yes, that's my understanding too, although I never program at such a level, so the rules are a little fuzzy in my head.

Comment: can  above code cause memory leak?

Comment: @harishDubakula It's UB, so yes, not that it matters.